# Best way to access an object stored in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, list

I have a `Student` class that contains an `ArrayList` of type `Course`, and `Course` is class with some fields like `className`, `classTime`, etc along with the appropriate getters and setters. Say I created an `ArrayList` of Course and have stored it into the `Student` class.

How can I for example print the `className` of a particular `Course` object (which is stored in an `ArrayList` stored in the `Student` class)?

So far I tried this, below is part of the code for class `Student`:

```
class Student {
    ArrayList<Course> studentSchedule;

    public ArrayList<Course> getStudentSchedule() {
        return studentSchedule;
    }

    public void setStudentSchedule(ArrayList<Course> studentSchedule) {
        this.studentSchedule = studentSchedule;
    }
}
```

Then I have some code that created `student1` of type `Student` and stored an `ArrayList` of `Course` into it.

Say I want to access the `className` in the first object in the `ArrayList` that's in `student1`. So far I have this and it works... is it fine?

```
ArrayList<Course> schedule = student1.getStudentSchedule();

System.out.print("\n course name at position 0 is " +
    student1.getStudentScheduleClassName(0));
```

It feels weird to create another `Arraylist` just for this purpose... but then I thought since in line 1, `schedule` will only contain the addresses that point to the location and shouldn't take much space?

Is there a more appropriate way to do this?

Comment: `ArrayList<Course> schedule = student1.getStudentSchedule();` This doesn't create a new ArrayList. It is just assigning the ArrayList in your student1 instance to a variable. You don't have a `getStudentScheduleClassName(...)` method in Student so i don't see how your example would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Course{
   private String className;
   public String getClassName(){
      return className;
    }
   public void setClassName(String c){
    className =c;
   }

}
```

So when you have this you can simply do
`System.out.println(student1.getStudentSchedule().get(0).getClassName())`

Comment: I can't do that unless I first define a getter with an integer first getStudentSchedule(int position); so are you suggesting I make more getters in the Student class?

Comment: I made small changes in my answer please look on last line. There you can do it because your getStudentSchedule() returns arrayList so you can simply invoke get(index) on it and get your Class object so on that object you can simply invoke getter ->getClassName()

Comment: THANK YOU! I realize what I was missing now, I was trying something like System.out.println(student1.getStudentSchedule(0).getClassName()) which confused me and I was starting to think the wrong way. The last line you added solved everything and I don't need to do something like creating another array as I did in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on above discussion I tried to complete the solution for my reference.

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class ListExample {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Student student1 = new Student();

    ArrayList<Course> student1Schedule = new ArrayList<Course>();
    student1Schedule.add(new Course("Computer Science", "Training Room"));
    student1Schedule.add(new Course("Mobile App Development", "Training Room 2"));

    student1.setStudentSchedule(student1Schedule);
    // Prints only one course 
    System.out.println(" ** Course" + student1.getStudentSchedule().get(0).toString());
    // Print all the courses attended by the student
    ArrayList<Course> studentDetails = student1.getStudentSchedule();
    Iterator<Course> studentIterator = studentDetails.iterator();
    while (studentIterator.hasNext()) {
        Course courseName = studentIterator.next();
        System.out.println(courseName);
    }

}


static class Student {

    private ArrayList<Course> studentSchedule;

    public ArrayList<Course> getStudentSchedule() {
        return studentSchedule;
    }

    public void setStudentSchedule(ArrayList<Course> studentSchedule) {
        this.studentSchedule = studentSchedule;
    } 
}

static class Course {

    private String courseName;
    private String className;

    public Course (String courseName, String className){
        this.className =className;
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }
    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }
    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }
    public String getClassName() {
        return className;
    }
    public void setClassName(String className) {
        this.className = className;
    }

    public String toString (){
        return "Course Name :" + this.courseName + "\n" + "Class Name : " + className + "\n";

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Make `className` into an instance variable of Course and have getter and setter methods within the Course for the class name.  Then you will print out the class name.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the first course's class name as:

```
System.out.print("\n course name at position 0 is " + schedule.get(0).getClassName());
```

since you've already defined getter/setter in the `Course` class as you mentioned.

Comment: To clarify, so it's okay to create another Arraylist called schedule like I did in my code just for the purpose of accessing the getters and setters in Course?

Comment: It's fine to create an arraylist in your code since a student can take multiple courses which naturally is suited for a list type.